# Eclipse 3.x trimbar in Eclipse 4.x

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, e4

Currently I am migrating a Eclipse RCP 3.7 application to an Eclipse 4.5 application. In the first step I have updated the target platform to Eclipse 4.5 and checking differences to the old version of the application.

In the new version the status bar height seems to be shrinked:
[image]

In the old version it looks like this:
[image]

I have tried to change from `menuContributions` (locationURI: `toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.trim.status`) in the *plugin.xml* to *ModelFragment->TrimContribution->Toolbar->Tool Controls* in *fragment.e4xmi*

Do I need to change the main CSS to adjust the height of the Toolbar? Which selector do I need to use?

Comment: I had the same problem and opened this bug [Status bar contributions are cut off](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=466609). See the last comment for a possible workaround.

Comment: Sorry, my initial answer was wrong. TrimContribution is OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Rüdigers hint I have figured out, how to add the ContributionItems without the shown cut off.

Firstly I have created a Handler:

```
public class TrimWidget extends AbstractHandler
{
    @Override
    public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and registered it as command in the plugin.xml:

```
<command
    defaultHandler="com.example.TrimWidget"
    id="com.example.trimWidget"
    name="-">
</command>
```

At last I have added the command to every ToolbarItem:

```
<toolbar id="com.example.statusBarItem">
    <control 
        class="com.example.MyStatusBarContribution"
        id="MyStatusBarContribution">
    </control>
    <command
        commandId="com.example.trimWidget"
        icon="icons/toolbar-command.png">
    </command>
</toolbar>
```

The result does not look like the version of Eclipse 3, but it is acceptable. The Items are left aligned in the status bar and cannot be moved via drag and drop.